# JSON.Net JsonConverter for DbGeography

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, json.net, spatial

Long long struggles with this...

Basically I have a model-first EF5 object with a `DbGeography` property. I would like to apply a `JsonConverter` that let's it roundtrip as simple latitude/longitude values. I'm using WebAPI.

Looking for JSON output and input like so:

```
{
    "location":
    {
        "geopoint":
        {
            "latitude":40.770712,
            "longitude":-73.962011
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my class definition and JsonConverter:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(QueryLocationMetadata))]
partial class Location
{
}

public class QueryLocationMetadata
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(DbGeographyConverter))]
    public virtual DbGeography GeoPoint { get; set; }
}


public class DbGeographyConverter : JsonConverter
{
    private const string LATITUDE_KEY = "latitude";
    private const string LONGITUDE_KEY = "longitude";

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType.Equals(typeof(DbGeography));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return default(DbGeography);

        var jObject = JObject.Load(reader);

        if (!jObject.HasValues || (jObject.Property(LATITUDE_KEY) == null || jObject.Property(LONGITUDE_KEY) == null))
            return default(DbGeography);

        string wkt = string.Format("POINT({1} {0})", jObject[LATITUDE_KEY], jObject[LONGITUDE_KEY]);
        return DbGeography.FromText(wkt, DbGeography.DefaultCoordinateSystemId);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var dbGeography = value as DbGeography;

        serializer.Serialize(writer, dbGeography == null || dbGeography.IsEmpty ? null : new { latitude = dbGeography.Latitude.Value, longitude = dbGeography.Longitude.Value });
    }
}
```

So using this I'm able to successfully serialize and even deserialize an object correctly but before I ever hit my `ApiController` action I get the following error:

```
System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.
   at System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDouble.get_Value()
   at GetValueFromSqlDouble(Object )
   at System.Web.Http.Metadata.Providers.AssociatedMetadataProvider`1.<>c__DisplayClass3.<GetMetadataForPropertiesImpl>b__0()
   at System.Web.Http.Metadata.ModelMetadata.get_Model()
   at System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateNodeAndChildren(ModelMetadata metadata, ValidationContext validationContext, Object container)
   at System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateProperties(ModelMetadata metadata, ValidationContext validationContext)
   at System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateNodeAndChildren(ModelMetadata metadata, ValidationContext validationContext, Object container)
   at System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateProperties(ModelMetadata metadata, ValidationContext validationContext)
   at System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateNodeAndChildren(ModelMetadata metadata, ValidationContext validationContext, Object container)
   at System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateProperties(ModelMetadata metadata, ValidationContext validationContext)
   at System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateNodeAndChildren(ModelMetadata metadata, ValidationContext validationContext, Object container)
   at System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateProperties(ModelMetadata metadata, ValidationContext validationContext)
   at System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateNodeAndChildren(ModelMetadata metadata, ValidationContext validationContext, Object container)
   at System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateElements(IEnumerable model, ValidationContext validationContext)
   at System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateNodeAndChildren(ModelMetadata metadata, ValidationContext validationContext, Object container)
   at System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateProperties(ModelMetadata metadata, ValidationContext validationContext)
   at System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateNodeAndChildren(ModelMetadata metadata, ValidationContext validationContext, Object container)
   at System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateElements(IEnumerable model, ValidationContext validationContext)
   at System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateNodeAndChildren(ModelMetadata metadata, ValidationContext validationContext, Object container)
   at System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.Validate(Object model, Type type, ModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider, HttpActionContext actionContext, String keyPrefix)
   at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.<>c__DisplayClass1.<ExecuteBindingAsync>b__0(Object model)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass36`1.<>c__DisplayClass38.<Then>b__35()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass49.<ToAsyncVoidTask>b__48()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.RunSynchronously[TResult](Func`1 func, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

After toying around and googling all sorts of things, I am absolutely at a loss. I get that in general it is attempting to validate the property but a SqlDouble?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue isn't with your converter. This is a known validation bug that happens when a public property's getter throws in the object graph. This work item tracks the issue:

http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/740

In the mean time, you should be able to get around it by disabling validation:

```
config.Services.Clear(typeof(ModelValidatorProvider));
```

Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Temporary or not, at least that lets me keep some of the hair on my head. Thanks!

Comment: You may have to use the fully qualified name: System.Web.Http.Validation.ModelValidatorProvider as mentioned here: https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/55

Comment: @Youssef, please have a look at the link in my answer. I'm curious to know if this is a known issue.

Comment: Really ? my hate toward MSSQL is getting over 9000

Answer (score 5):

The bug mentioned by Youssef has since been fixed, but I still ran into issues when creating a custom `JsonConverter` for `DbGeography` in that somewhere in the validation process the `DefaultBodyModelValidator` got stuck in a loop. My solution was not to disable model validation altogether, but to replace the default validator with a derived one that excludes the `DbGeography` type from deep validation.

So as not to repeat myself, [you can see the full solution here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19941808/exclude-a-type-from-model-validation/19964146#19964146)

Comment: you saved me another day of rage, this DbGeogrphy is .... really the worthless type i ever seen in my life.

Comment: 8 years later we still run into new problems that it causes across our systems. To some extent we regret leveraging it.