# Posting models with NodaTime auto-props to WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, nodatime

We are in the process of using NodaTime for time / date models in our project. The project is a web application, using WebAPI. When attempting to post a model containing LocalTime autoprops, we receive an InsufficientExecutionStackException.

In order to isolate our project from this issue, I created a new WebAPI project. Using NuGet, I added NodaTime and NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet to the project. In `Startup.cs`, I used `ConfigureForNodaTime` as such:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(x =>
{
    x.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Clear();
    x.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ConfigureForNodaTime(
    DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb);
});
```

In the (boilerplate) `ValuesController.cs` file, I hijacked `Post` as such:

```
// POST api/values
public void Post(TestClass input)
{
    var x = input;
}

public class TestClass
{
    public LocalTime Open { get; set; }
    public LocalTime Close { get; set; }
}
```

When posting this input model (via postman), rather than receiving local times, I receive the error at the end of this post.

If we rewrite `TestClass` as shown, no errors occur, and we get the correct local times:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public LocalTime;
    public LocalTime;
}
```

**Is there something I can do to get the application to work with autoprops? While I can (and probably will) start replacing autoprops with fields, it would be nice to understand what's going on here.**

Here's the entire error, with 800 arbitrary lines removed from the middle:

```
{
"message":"An error has occurred.",
"exceptionMessage":"Insufficient stack to continue executing the program safely. This can happen from having too many functions on the call stack or function on the stack using too much stack space.",
"exceptionType":"System.InsufficientExecutionStackException",
"stackTrace":"   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.EnsureSufficientExecutionStack()
    at System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateNodeAndChildren(ModelMetadata metadata, ValidationContext validationContext, Object container, IEnumerable`1 validators)
    at System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateProperties(ModelMetadata metadata, ValidationContext validationContext)
    at System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateNodeAndChildren(ModelMetadata metadata, ValidationContext validationContext, Object container, IEnumerable`1 validators)
    at System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateElements(IEnumerable model, ValidationContext validationContext)
    at System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateNodeAndChildren(ModelMetadata metadata, ValidationContext validationContext, Object container, IEnumerable`1 validators)
    at System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateProperties(ModelMetadata metadata, ValidationContext validationContext)
    at System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateNodeAndChildren(ModelMetadata metadata, ValidationContext validationContext, Object container, IEnumerable`1 validators)
    at System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateProperties(ModelMetadata metadata, ValidationContext validationContext)
    at System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateNodeAndChildren(ModelMetadata metadata, ValidationContext validationContext, Object container, IEnumerable`1 validators)
    at System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateProperties(ModelMetadata metadata, ValidationContext validationContext)
    at System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateNodeAndChildren(ModelMetadata metadata, ValidationContext validationContext, Object container, IEnumerable`1 validators)
    at System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateProperties(ModelMetadata metadata, ValidationContext validationContext)
    at System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateNodeAndChildren(ModelMetadata metadata, ValidationContext validationContext, Object container, IEnumerable`1 validators)
    at System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateProperties(ModelMetadata metadata, ValidationContext validationContext)
    at System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateNodeAndChildren(ModelMetadata metadata, ValidationContext validationContext, Object container, IEnumerable`1 validators)
    at System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateProperties(ModelMetadata metadata, ValidationContext validationContext)
    at System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateNodeAndChildren(ModelMetadata metadata, ValidationContext validationContext, Object container, IEnumerable`1 validators)
    at System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateProperties(ModelMetadata metadata, ValidationContext validationContext)
    at System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateNodeAndChildren(ModelMetadata metadata, ValidationContext validationContext, Object container, IEnumerable`1 validators)
    at System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateProperties(ModelMetadata metadata, ValidationContext validationContext)
    at System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateNodeAndChildren(ModelMetadata metadata, ValidationContext validationContext, Object container, IEnumerable`1 validators)
    at System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.Validate(Object model, Type type, ModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider, HttpActionContext actionContext, String keyPrefix)
    at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.<ExecuteBindingAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
    at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionBinding.<ExecuteBindingAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
    at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
    at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
    at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__0.MoveNext()"
}
```

Comment: Could you try it against Noda Time 2.0? I can make a pre-release Nuget build if that would help... there are lots of breaking changes in 2.0, so this would just be very temporary - but it would be nice to know whether or not it fixes the issue.

Comment: I'd gladly test it against Noda Time 2.0, but I don't know how to get it.

Comment: Either you can just fetch the source and build it yourself, or I can build and publish a pre-release Nuget package. Are you using the Nuget package at the moment?

Comment: I'm using the Nuget package currently. I don't mind checking the project out myself, but it will have to wait until later today.

Comment: Okay - it would be useful for me to build a pre-release version for other reasons anyway; I'll get on that this evening, and ping here when it's done. Thanks so much!

Comment: Right - it's available as https://www.nuget.org/packages/NodaTime/2.0.0-alpha20140807. There are various backwardly-incompatible changes, but hopefully you won't hit them just for this test...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears to be a WebAPI issue, but I don't fully understand the root cause,  nor do I particularly like this solution.  However, based on [the code in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19941808/634824), I came up with a workaround:

```
public class CustomBodyModelValidator : DefaultBodyModelValidator
{
    public override bool ShouldValidateType(Type type)
    {
        return type.Namespace != "NodaTime" && base.ShouldValidateType(type);
    }
}
```

In your configuration lambda (or wherever you are accessing the global WebAPI configuration:

```
x.Services.Replace(typeof(IBodyModelValidator), new CustomBodyModelValidator());
```

Consider this a hack of a workaround until I (or someone else) can figure out a better solution.  Thanks.

**Update:** On further research, it appears this has already been posted to the Noda Time issue tracker as [issue #249](https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime/issues/249), and a similar solution was proposed.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for the issue online, but apparently my google-fu has failed me.

Comment: Due to the closure of google code, the issue is now hosted at https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime/issues/249

Comment: @Jamezor - Thanks. Updated.