# c# Json.net DbGeography deserialize error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, json.net

I am trying to get Spartial Data from a Database and then Serialize it (working great).
When I try to deserialize that Data a JsonSerializationException is thrown.

```
DbGeography geoPoint = CreatePoint(40.7056308, -73.9780035);
string serializedPoint = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(geoPoint);
DbGeography resjson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DbGeography>(serializedPoint);
```

Here is the CreatePoint Method:

```
public static DbGeography CreatePoint(double latitude, double longitude)
{
string text = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat,
"POINT({0} {1})", longitude, latitude);
return DbGeography.PointFromText(text, 4326);
}
```

I produced this Error in a Console Application.

```
Nuget Packages installed: 
EntityFramework 6.1.0
Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.3
```

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [edit help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Your original question was one wall of text, and your code was hidden. Formatting in [SO] is different that other sites.

Comment: And what is the message when you get *JsonSerializationException* ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`System.Data.Spatial.DbGeography` (which I assume you are using) is not suitable for deserialization by Newtonsoft.Json. You do not mention the thrown exception, but the one I observe is:

> Unable to find a constructor to use for type
>   System.Data.Spatial.DbGeography. A class should either have a default
>   constructor, one constructor with arguments or a constructor marked
>   with the JsonConstructor attribute.

You can resolve this by providing the serialization/deserialization logic yourself by means of a `JsonConverter`. I've used the one from [JSON.Net JsonConverter for DbGeography](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14147299/json-net-jsonconverter-for-dbgeography) and slightly modified it to fix a bug for my local culture (which uses ',' as the decimal separator):

```
public class DbGeographyConverter : JsonConverter
{
    private const string LATITUDE_KEY = "latitude";
    private const string LONGITUDE_KEY = "longitude";

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType.Equals(typeof(DbGeography));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return default(DbGeography);

        var jObject = JObject.Load(reader);

        if (!jObject.HasValues || (jObject.Property(LATITUDE_KEY) == null || jObject.Property(LONGITUDE_KEY) == null))
            return default(DbGeography);

        string wkt = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "POINT({1} {0})", jObject[LATITUDE_KEY], jObject[LONGITUDE_KEY]);
        return DbGeography.FromText(wkt, DbGeography.DefaultCoordinateSystemId);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var dbGeography = value as DbGeography;

        serializer.Serialize(writer, dbGeography == null || dbGeography.IsEmpty ? null : new { latitude = dbGeography.Latitude.Value, longitude = dbGeography.Longitude.Value });
    }
}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
DbGeography geoPoint = CreatePoint(40.7056308, -73.9780035);
string serializedPoint = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(geoPoint, new DbGeographyConverter());
DbGeography resjson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DbGeography>(serializedPoint, new DbGeographyConverter());
```

Comment: Tanks TC! That helped me a lot!