# Bind System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography to MVC Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, dbgeography

I have an MVC model with a DBGeometry field

```
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Location is required")]
    public System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography LocationGps { get; set; } // LocationGPS
```

Inside my View i have this hidden values.

```
 @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.LocationGps)
 @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Lat)
 @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Lng)
```

When I edit the model I write the following to my Controller

```
   model.LocationGps = Utils.Geography.ConvertLatLonToDbGeography(model.Lng, model.Lat);
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {}
```

ConvertLatLonToDbGeography code:

```
   public static DbGeography ConvertLatLonToDbGeography(double longitude, double latitude)
    {
        var point = string.Format("POINT({1} {0})", latitude, longitude);
        return DbGeography.FromText(point);
    }
```

But ModelState is always Invalid because LocationGps is null. how can I set properly values to my LocationGps parameter through my View? 
The consept is to have a google map, get the coords from javascript (stored in Lat & Lng fields) and then set my LocationGps properly. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

My problem solved with these steps:

1. Add a JSonConverter inside my Model (JsonConverter found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14147299/json-net-jsonconverter-for-dbgeography))

   ```
   [JsonConverter(typeof(DbGeographyConverter))]
   [Required]
    public System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography LocationGps { get; set; }
   ```
2. Serialize my datatable (server side)

   ```
   string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataTableData);
   return Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   ```
3. called JSON.parse (client side) because my dataSrc has other values except from list of results

   ```
      "ajax":
               {
                   "url": "@string.Format("{0}",Url.Content("~/Location/AjaxGetLocations"))",
                   "type": "POST",
                   "dataSrc": function (data) {
                       var json = JSON.parse(data);
                       return json["data"];
                   }
               },
     "columns": [
               { "data": "LocationID", "orderable": false, "visible": false },
               { "data": "LocationInternalCode", "orderable": false },
               { "data": "LocationName", "orderable": false },
       etc....
   ```

   I post it to save others from time. Very disappointed that no one had an answer to my question once again...